# Center navigation bar using css

Tags: html, css, navigation

I am really struggling to get my horizontal nav bar to center. I have tried a mixture of display:inline-block; code but to no avail, does anyone know how I could try things differently.

HTML Code

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="navcontainer" class="navlist" style="background: #99ccff;"> 
        <ul id="navlist">
            <li><a id="link1"  onmouseover="chbg('#99ccff')" onMouseOut="chbg('#99ccff')" href="#">Products</a></li>
            <li><a id="link2" onmouseover="chbg('#ff9999')" onMouseOut="chbg('#99ccff')"  href="#">Holidays / Travel</a></li>
            <li><a id="link3" onmouseover="chbg('#ffff99')" onMouseOut="chbg('#99ccff')"  href="#">Motors / Transport</a></li>
            <li><a id="link4" onmouseover="chbg('#99cc66')" onMouseOut="chbg('#99ccff')"  href="#">Services</a></li>
        </ul>
        <br style="clear:right"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS Code

```
.navlist {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #333; 
    padding-top: 90px; 
    text-align:center;
}

.navlist ul {
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
    float: left;
}

.navlist ul li {
    display:inline;
}

.navlist ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white; 
    padding: 0px 20px;
    display:inline-block;
}

.navlist ul li a:visited {
    color: #333;
}

.navlist ul li a:hover, .menu ul li .current {
    color: #333;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `float: left` from `.navlist ul`, check this [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/vFDrV/).

Answer (score 1):

```
.navlist ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    /*float: left;*/
}
```

remove float:left

http://jsfiddle.net/Ar3BV/

Answer (score 0):

You should try setting margin-left and margin-right to auto.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following css. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4nkY9/)

```
.navlist{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #333333; 
    padding-top: 90px; 
    text-align:center;
    margin-left: auto ;
    margin-right: auto ;
}

.navlist ul
{
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
}


.navlist ul li{
    display:inline;
}

.navlist ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white; 
    padding: 0px 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

remove `float:left` from

```
.navlist ul {
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
    float: left;
}
```

and add

```
.navcontainer{
float: center;
}
```

It will work

Answer (score 0):

Update your css as

```
  .navlist ul {
        margin: 0 auto; 
        padding: 0;
    }
```

Check [here](http://jsbin.com/UJEZUwu/1)